# Include date in web publishing package filename; visual studio

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, timestamp, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

When creating a new deployment package (e.g. per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx) you're asked to provide a package location.

I'd like to append a timestamp to this filename, so that I can easily access older versions, just by browsing the output location.

i.e. I'd like to specify a value such as this:  Packages\Test\MyProject`{yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss}`.zip
...where the values in the braces are replaced by the current date/time.

Is this possible through native visual studio?
If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Is that really necessary? The metadata for the file will include the date and time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RamsaySmith; however if newly created files have the same name the original would be overwritten.  If there's some way to avoid that (e.g. generate a new guid, or add a version number to the filename) that would be better; but I don't know if that's possible either.  A script could be used to add a timestamp or copy/move the file - but it would be better if there was a way to do this directly from VS.

Comment: You can do that using a MSBuild script. I will provide more details in a moment, too bad the bouty will be expired by then :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do that by editing your csproj file as follows (you have to open it as a text file):
- Near the end of the file you will find a comment with the targets AfterBuild and BeforeBuild, right after this comment add the following code

```
<Target Name="OnBeforePublishMyProject">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_PackageTempDir>H:\Cs\Test\build.$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"))</_PackageTempDir>
      <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PublishMyProject" DependsOnTargets="Build;OnBeforePublishMyProject;PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
  </Target>
```

- Now you can Publish your project using the Visual Studio Command prompt and the following commands:

  ```
  cd path_to_your_project

  msbuild /t:PublishMyProject
  ```

You can create a bat file to execute those commands too